# How to execule file from the cached file in html5 offline?

Tags: html, caching, offline

I wrote a cache.manifest for my html5 page (index.php)

The content in cache manifest:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

#version 1.0 09-16-2011
CACHE:
/images/app.jpg
/css/app.css
/js/app/js

NETWORK:
*
```

The static files are cached ok, but the host file index.php is cached too.
If i remove the cache.manifest from index.php, it'll never be cached.

How can i exculde index.php from the cached files?

Answer (score 2):

It's **not** possible to **exclude** the linking page (at least for now... HTML5 is still a draft) from the cacheing process.

PS: it's also incorrect to speak about .manifest, while W3C introduced a new definition .appcache (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to exclude it is not to link to the manifest from it.  Pages which reference a manifest file are *always* cached.

Answer (score -1):

If you don’t want to cache `index.php` add it to the `NETWORK` section of your manifest: resources in there are never cached and aren’t available off-line.

Comment: As mentioned in the other answers, the page that links to the cache.manifest file will always be cached, even if it is included in the NETWORK section.

Comment: Yes, I didn’t really expand the point in my answer (so it deserves the down-vote). This is an odd situation; I fail to see the point in going to the bother of using an app cache for a handful of assets and no actual _pages_. If it’s about performance, a sensible web caching strategy coupled with optimised images and CSS should be sufficient.